# Spring LdapTemplate - how to modify the ContextSource configuration

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-ldap, spring-security-ldap

I'm looking for a way to change the username for LDAP identification. I'll explain:

I receiving this in my class :

```
@Autowired
LdapTemplate ldapPRD; //prod environnement
@Autowired
LdapTemplate ldapQLT //quality environnemnt
```

And if I'm not mistaken, this LdapTemplate object is configured according to my application.yml file :

```
ldap:
  uid: system
  user: uid=${ldap.uid},ou=people,dc=huff,dc=com
    prod:
      url: ldap://prod.dfd.huff.com:389 //prod environnement
      pwd: p
   qlt:
      url: ldap://qlt.dfd.huff.com:389 // quality environnement
...
```

And this is the "system" that's used to connect to ldap.

So, my question is how can I change "system" for another user with LdapTemplate ?

I need to know who's doing what in LDAP.And I can't modify the application.yml because the user "system" is already used at another place in the application.

I have to manage different environments that configure the LdapTemplate differently.

```
public boolean testADMCredential(Credential credential, Environment env) {
    LdapTemplate ldap = chooseLdapConfig(env);
  
    ...
}
```

thanks for your help. :)

Comment: Will you endup with multiple LdapTemplate ?

Comment: Yes, I have to work with multiple LdapTemplate wish corresponds to different environments. I've edited my post. I hope that answers your question.

Comment: Are you creating something to deal with multiple Ldap at the same time ? Because, an other answer would be to use profile, by do you need both LDAP active at the same time ?

Comment: No, just one active. (the function chooseLdapConfig(env) return a LdapTemplate corresponds to the "env" parameter).

Comment: Have you heard about profile in Spring ?

Comment: I solved the problem, thanks for your help !!

Comment: Can you post your answer ?

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your LdapTemplate like this
and use it

```
    public LdapTemplate getServerLdapTemplate(){
      
      // Fetch existing one created by Spring
      LdapContextSource contextSource = (LdapContextSource) ldapTemplate.getContextSource();
      
      // Modify it as per requirement
      contextSource.setUrl("ldap://ldap.forumsys.com:389");
      contextSource.setBase("dc=example,dc=com");
      contextSource.setUserDn("cn=read-only-admin,dc=example,dc=com");
      contextSource.setPassword("password");
      
      // Important to apply the changes you made
      contextSource.afterPropertiesSet();
      ldapTemplate.setContextSource(contextSource);
      
      // Return the template and use it
      return ldapTemplate;

   }
```